# How to modify a preferential attachment model

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to code a preferential attachment model where each new node connects to 4 old nodes, not one. The centerpiece of the program is a procedure that selects a list of 4 nodes, where each node's probability of being in the list is proportional to their degree, i.e. # of link-neighbors. Here is the code:

```
to-report find-partners
  let temp-turtles sort turtles
  let result []

  repeat 4 [
    set temp-turtles shuffle temp-turtles
    if not empty? temp-turtles [
      let total-neighbors sum (map (count link-neighbors) temp-turtles)
      let pick random-float total-neighbors
      let winner nobody

      foreach temp-turtles [
        x ->
        let turtle-neighbors [count link-neighbors] of x
        if winner = nobody [
          ifelse pick < first turtle-neighbors [
            set winner x
          ] [
            set pick pick - first turtle-neighbors
          ]
        ]
      ]

      if winner != nobody [
        set temp-turtles remove-item (position winner temp-turtles) temp-turtles
        set result lput winner result
      ]
    ]
  ]

  report result
end
```

I keep on getting errors relating to the 'map' and 'of' syntax. I'm new to Netlogo so would really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `map` is that you have used parentheses rather than brackets around `count link-neighbors`.  `map` needs an anonymous procedure, which requires brackets to be recognized.  But, I think that you are using map unnecessarily.  It looks like you are trying to sum the number of link neighbors of all the `temp-turtles`.  Simply using

```
let total-neighbors sum [count link-neighbors] of temp-turtles
```

should do the trick.  The `of` will give you a list of the number of link neighbors of each temp-turtle, which you can sum directly.

It's not clear to me what problem you are having with `of`.  It appears to be used correctly.  Could you elaborate?

Finally, I wonder about your use of `pick`.  I know this was not your question, but `pick` could conceivably be a very large number, certainly greater than the number of link neighbors of any given turtle.  I suspect that your

```
ifelse pick < first turtle-neighbors
```

won't be true very often.